# Circular dependency from generated database entities when exporting to json

Tags: java, mysql, json, jpa

I have a database that looks like this

[image: db]

All tables but the `recipe` one has a

```
recipe_id int not null, foreign key (recipe_id) references recipes(id)
```

I generated my entities automatically using JPA tool from eclipse but instead of the foreign key `recipe_id` I get something like

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Recipe
@ManyToOne
private Recipe recipe;
```

For example, when I try to export all of my recipes into a json format I get a stackoverflow exception and that's because when it writes the json, it gets to allergens, my allergens class has a Recipe object (that points to the Recipe that has those certain allergens) so it writes that Recipe object again and so on forever.

Also, when I try to simply print a recipe out I get the following output, considering all my foreign keys were set correctly when I added the data from mysql

```
allergens={IndirectList: not instantiated}, ingredients={IndirectList: not instantiated}, mediaitems={IndirectList: not instantiated}, nutritionvalues={IndirectList: not instantiated}, steps={IndirectList: not instantiated}
```

I hope it makes sense.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think such errors happens when you try to export in json a variable that is infinitly nested... I don't know if that makes sens.. but like you could do yourVar.List.Table.List.Table.List...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Like you said "... so it writes that Recipe object again ans so on forever". I'm not sure why you would have recipe_id in every table if they are not linked to that table.. I get that Recipe is the main table, but I'm not sure what nutritionvalues is

Comment: It is just another table that has a foreign key for recipe. I know the way the diagram looks that table seems special but is really not

Answer (score 0):

Export to json is trying to serialize your java beans into textual form. In java, it is very common and usefull to have bidrectional associations like the one between your recipe and mediaitem. Both objects have a reference to each other. However, such cyclic association can not be represented in json or in fact any textual form as they are inherently flat tree-like structures.

The way most json marshallers work, is that they inspect the object instance which is supposed to be serialized, and iterate over all of its accessible attributes. For each attribute, the marshaller will again invoke the function in a recursive way. Therefore if you have cyclic association, the recursion will go on forever until the jvm runs out of stack memory-hence the stwckOverflowException.

As this is a common issue, there are several solutions available. Some json libs support cycle detection and when they discover a cyclic association to an object that is already in their stack, they will not try to marshall it again - instead it gets ignored or only it's Id is printed. Have a look at [Jackson's backreference](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences) for example.

The other strategy is to separate your data model from your json model, commonly referred to as DTO mapping. In this case you create a new set of pojo classes similar to your entities and have some kind of beanmapper that maps entity to dtos and vice versa. That way you can control the associations and remove any cycles before you submit the data to json serializer.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply.

So I've used `@JsonBackReference` for the arrays in the `Recipe` class and `@JsonManagedReference` for the Recipe object in the other classes but for some reason I still get the stack overflow.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Also tried `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")` at the top of each class and no luck

Comment: You need to handle all bidirectional associations in order to avoid the stackoverflow exc. Also, are you sure that you are using Jackson as marshaller(e.g. what server or lib are you using)?